# Consider $E_f = \{(x,(x,f(x)))| x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ for an arbitrary function, $[E_f]_x$ is a borel set

Tags: real-analysis

I have some sort of struggles solving this problem,
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary function, and $E_f = \{(x,(x,f(x)))| x \in \mathbb{R}   \}$. I have to show that cross sections $[E_f]_x$ and $[E_f]^{(x,y)}$ are Borel sets. Also I have to show that $E_f$ is not necessarily a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I think Both $[E_f]_x$ and $[E_f]^{(x,y)}$ are single points or an empty set, that is why they are Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively.

For the second part I need to know that what Borel subsets of $R^3$ look like, then I can give a counter example.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a non-measurable set $V$ like the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) and take $f = \chi_V$ its characteristic function. If $E_{\chi_V}$ was a Borel set then $E_{\chi_V} \cap \{\mathbb R \times \{1\}\} = V \cap \{1\}$ would be Borel. Which is not the case as it not even measurable.